# Multiple NavigatorControllers

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to get started with a Navigator Controller tutorial, but I couldn't find one in which there are multiple navigation controllers.

I have the following code so far: the first page is a simple main menu using a `UIViewController`. By pressing the first button the user can go to a customers list page using `UINavigationController` and the Back button correctly appeared on the navigation bar of the customers list page.

In my app delegate, I have the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
}
```

In the view controller which is responsible for displaying the customer list, the back button invokes the following method:

```
- (void)backHome:(id)sender {       
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    appDelegate.window.rootViewController =  viewController;

    [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];

    // self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];       
}
```

But it stopped working. I'm not sure how can I make this work.

Comment: English. Formatting. Whitespace. Indentation. Documentation. Effort.

Answer (score 1):

Set a `UINavigationController` as your rootViewController on the `UIWindow`, like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
}
```

Then just pop the viewController on the stack when going back, like this:

```
-(void)backHome:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, If i dont want to have UINavigationController on load,
and have only UIViewController to show menu.
This will do the same for second menu for instance FoodMenu it will use UITabNavigation. In the way it will got back button to Main Menu (UIVIEWCOntroller)

Answer (score 0):

To really get your head around the basics of iOS, I recommend buying a book and learning properly. Just recently I got the Big Nerd Ranch book about iOS and I've found it quite helpful. Good luck with your adventures!

To answer your question, Markus has it right, you need a rootViewController, from which you push other views on top of it (e.g. when a button is pushed), and to go back to the main view, you pop the one on top.

Comment: Thanks for your recommend, I already did some tutorial and 3 days courses already. But what I got from tutorial, it is about only one UINavigatorCOntroller or UITabCOntroller for 1 project. However what I try to do is 
Mainmenu(UIViewController)
 - Customer List (UINavigationCOntroller)
 - FoodMenu (UiTabController)

so if you know any tutorials and books, please advice, Thx.